# Java Script not running on server control ASP.Net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datepicker

I would like to use the jQuery-UI  datepicker on a asp:TextBox control.
Here is my syntax for the script:

```
<script> $(function(){$document.getElementById('<%txtvBdayEd.ClientID%>').datepicker({dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"});
        });
</script>
```

it is not working and I am curious is that incorrect?

My id comes from

```
<asp:Textbox id="txtvBdayEd" CssClass="txtBoxes"  runat="server" Text="PlaceHolder"></asp:Textbox>
```

Comment: your element selector looks odd to me.  'getElementById('<%txtvBdayEd.ClientID%>')' is there really a DOM element with an id attribute of '<%txtvBdayEd.ClientID%>'?

Comment: Shouldn't that be <%=txtvBdayEd.ClientId%>

Comment: @cobolstinks that gest evaluated and printed on server

Comment: To see if the HTML generated is correct, you should inspect the element with your browsers developer tools.

Comment: That is actually the name of my text box:  <asp:Textbox id="txtvBdayEd" CssClass="txtBoxes"  runat="server" Text="PlaceHolder"></asp:Textbox>

Comment: try `$('#<%=txtvBdayEd.ClientId%>').datepicker..` or change `$document` to `$(document`. Check browser console for errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a slight syntax error in the ASP.NET code to generate the client side ID, and also you've confused the jQuery and standard JS syntax for fetching an element.

The ASP bit needs an = just before the <%, and for the script part, $document probably doesn't evaluate to anything. document.getElementById would get you the JS element, but the datepicker method needs to be called on a jQuery object (which wraps the JS element). This is done using the $(selector) syntax:

```
$("#<%=txtvBdayEd.ClientID%>").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
```

should work properly.

Comment: I just want to add one small change to the solution ClientId should be ClientID as it is case sensitive..

Comment: @TommyMcGee done, thanks. Been a while since I've used ASP.NET Forms, you soon forget these little details!